# What's the easiest way to move data from a PostgreSQL database to a new MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

All of the questions I find are about moving from MySQL to PSQL and I need to do the opposite. I only want to do this in order to use MySQLi (this site is backed-up to Heroku and my server as well as my development machine which means a database switch could be a never-ending headache) but I could definitely use a PSQL friendly interface instead of MySQLi if I need to.

Which way is the easiest for getting PSQL data into a new MySQL database?

Comment: if your on a mac use sequel pro. im not sure if it does psql though. use some kind of software to do it for you.

Comment: My development machine is a Mac and my server runs Ubuntu.

Comment: Well no wonder that there are far more articles and Q&As about moving from mysql to postgresql. There's hardly ever a reason to move the other way round.

Comment: You know what? I think I'll use a PSQL module instead of MySQLi. This seems like the easiest solution. I'm going to leave this question over, though. Just in case someone has better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked the easiest way. I would say try product like [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/download/navicat-premium). They give 15 days free trial I think. Give it a try. P.S. I do not work for Navicat.